# install Vestacp facing issues?

Tags: bash

i upgrade my ubuntu 17.04 to 18.04 LTS and i try to install the Vestacp using these below comments:

```
curl -O http://vestacp.com/pub/vst-install.sh
sudo bash vst-install.sh
```

but its shows some error like

```
Length: 47107 (46K) [text/plain]
Saving to: ‘vst-install-ubuntu.sh’

vst-install-ubuntu. 100%[===================>]  46.00K   257KB/s    in 0.2s    

2018-05-12 18:17:00 (257 KB/s) - ‘vst-install-ubuntu.sh’ saved [47107/47107]

Error: No access to Vesta repository
```

i tried a lot?

how to resolve the issues?

Comment: Maybe vestacp repo doesn't exist for 18.04!

Comment: You should contact vestacp.com and request support for 18.04 LTS.